# How to add £(pound) before every price in php?

Tags: php, regex, explode

I have two amount like `10-250` i want to show £(pound) symbol in every amount and give one `space` each between `hyphen` and `amount` it looks like `£10 - £250` Please suggest me any regular expression have there for adding the £ in every price amount.

```
ex : -
1-10 = £1 - £10
10-20-30 = £10 - £20 -£30
500-600-800 = £500 - £600 - £800
```

***EDIT:***

```
Code:
//$priceStr = urldecode($this->params['named']['price']);
$priceStr = '10-250';
$getExplodePrice = explode('-',$priceStr);
foreach($getExplodePrice as $newPrice){
    $price[] = '£'.$newPrice.' -';
}

echo implode(' ',$price);
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Or did some research ?

Comment: I have tried but not getting any solution. :(

Comment: Include your attempts then

Comment: Sure. just wait i am editing my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to add a pound sign to the number and put spaces around the hyphens)

```
<?php

    $str = "10-20-30";  
    echo $str = preg_replace("/(\d+)(-)?/", "£$1 $2 ", $str);

?>
```

Output:

```
£1 - £10
£10 - £20 - £30
£500 - £600 - £800
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions for this:

```
// 500-600-800 to £500 - £600 - £800
echo convert('500-600-800');

function convert($str)
{
    $parts = explode('-', $str);
    return '£'.implode(' - £', $parts);
}
```

You might want to consider using `&pound;` instead of `£`, depends what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode()` and `array_reduce()` for that:

```
$priceStr = '10-250-2';
echo array_reduce(explode('-', $priceStr), function($result, $item) {
    if(!empty($result)) {
        return "$result - £$item";
    } else {
        return "£$item";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex that will not re-add any pound symbols:

`(?<!£)\b(\d+)\b`

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/sR5xL0/1).

Demo code:

```
$re = "/(?<!£)\\b(\\d+)\\b/"; 
$str = "1-10\n10-20-30\n500-600-800\n£500"; 
$subst = "£$1"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

See, `£500` is not replaced with `££500`